# invoke the app and upload data on server when iphone is connected to internet

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am making an ios application in which i need to take some data from user and upload them on server . but some time internet connection will not be available
at that time . So I want when my device is connected to internet , My app will sent that data to server

Comment: Look at Reachability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using Reachability. It have many methods to check internet availability Or you can also get sample code from Apple. 
Follow this URL: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.htmle

Whenever network status changes **reachabilityChanged** get call and you can check whether internet is available or not in reachabilityChanged method.

```
@interface ViewController ()

 @property (nonatomic) Reachability *hostReachability;

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

 self.hostReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
 [self.hostReachability startNotifier];

}
```

// Called by Reachability whenever network status changes,

```
(void)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [self.hostReachability currentReachabilityStatus];

    if (networkStatus == NotReachable) {
        //no internet connection
    }
    else {
        //internet available send your code to server
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use third Party Library Reachability Classes. And write the code in ViewWillAppear.

```
 Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
if (internetStatus != NotReachable) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    });
}
else {
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Please check Your Internet connection" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```